# Check checkboxes in table with selenium until last index page of a table

Tags: java, selenium

Here are the app snapshots:
[App snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjln8.png)
[After clicking checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNgYn.png)
[After making selection from dialog;displaysX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q1og.png)

I am writing a selenium Java code for a oracle apps that has a table with checkboxes in one column out of 4. I need to click on each checkbox-> perform some function until last item in one page then click on second page and repeat the steps until last item in all pages. I am able to click and perform function easily but it doesn't stop at the last item and keep on trying to click on the first item again on which ever page driver is on. Here is what I have written and tried many combinations.

```
List<WebElement> stores = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'gridview-1157')]/tbody/tr/td[1]"));
System.out.println(stores.size());

while(stores.size()>0) 
{
    for(int i = 1; i<stores.size(); i++) 
    {

        System.out.println(stores.get(i).getText());
        stores.get(i).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //String ErrorCodeCombo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text x-form-text-default  ' and @readonly])")).getAttribute("id");
        String ErrorCodeCombo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'inv-applyerrorcode-')]//*[starts-with(@data-ref,'inputEl')]")).getAttribute("id");
        driver.findElement(By.id(ErrorCodeCombo)).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id(ErrorCodeCombo)).sendKeys(org.openqa.selenium.Keys.DOWN,org.openqa.selenium.Keys.ENTER);
        String buttonCode = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class=\"x-btn x-unselectable x-box-item x-btn-default-small\"])[1]")).getAttribute("id");
        driver.findElement(By.id(buttonCode)).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        stores = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'gridview-1157')]/tbody/tr/td[1]"));
        int count = stores.size()-1;
        String lastItem=stores.get(count).getText();
        System.out.println("lastItem is " +lastItem);
        if(stores.get(i).getText().equals(lastItem)) { //This is something I just tried to break the loop
            break;
        }                           
    }

    String nextBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='button-1139']")).getAttribute("class");
    String disableClass = "x-item-disabled";
    if(!nextBtn.contains(disableClass)) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("button-1139-btnIconEl")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        stores = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'gridview-1157')]/tbody/tr/td[1]"));
        System.out.println(stores.size());
    }
}
```

In the I am getting error that element not found for ErrorCodeCombo because it is no more clickable anymore.

Please guide me on how to break the loop in the end and stop the script with success.
Also attaching a snapshot of the app. In my snapshot example I want to click from 1 to 39 and stop.

Comment: Add html in text format, maybe link to online text editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get full context from your code but here would be my approach for this task:

1. Get total number of pages (if possible), lets store it in `i`

2. Lets create another variable `j` to iterate through each page

```
for(j=0;j<=i;j++){// to iterate through each page

    // Now find all checkboxes on the page and store the size in k

    for(int l=0;l<=k;l++){         // to iterate through each checkboxe

         //Do your click checkbox action here

     }

    //if its last page I guess you don't want to click on next page, so

    if(j==i){
        System.out.println("No more pages to click");
    }else{
        //click on next page
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I am able to execute it successfully with the approach you mentioned. FYI- There is no pages to calculate so I did some math like total/perpage and then math.ceil. Only thing I changed in your code is j<i not j<=i and it worked perfectly. Thanks man for the help.